# pandas -Merging on date columns is not working

Tags: python, pandas, date, merge

*hello stackoverflow community. I am having an issue while trying to do a simple merge between two dataframes which share the same date column. sorry I am new to python and perhaps the way I express myself is not very clear. I am working on the project related to stock prices calculation. the first data frame has date and closing prices columns, while the second one only has similar date column. my goal is to obtain a single date column which will have matching closing prices column next to it.*

*this is what I have done to merge two dataframes*
`inner_join = pd.merge(df.iloc[7:79],df1[['Ex-Date','FDX UN Equity']],on ='Ex-date',how ='inner')`

`inner_join`

*Ex-date refers to date column and FXD UN Equity refers to column with closing prices*

*I get this as a result:*

````
) = self._get_merge_keys() 
# validate the merge keys dtypes. We may need to coerce
# Check for duplicates
# work-around for merge_asof(right_index=True)
KeyError: 'Ex-date'```
````

*Pandas read the format of date columns differently, so I made the same format for date columns in original excel file but it hasn't helped. I tried all sorts of various merges but it didn't work either.*
*anyone have any ideas what is going on?*

Comment: can you show the df.head(). Its hard to tell whats going on just by seeing this

Comment: selecting columns by label is **case sensitive**. You select `df1[['Ex-Date',...]]` then try to merge on `'Ex-date'`, notice the different capitalization on the `D` in Date

Answer (score 0):

The code would look like this

```
    import pandas as pd
    inner_join = pd.merge_asof(df, df1, on = 'Ex-date')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change both column header name to the same lower case  and merge again.. check Ex-Date.. the column name header should be the same before you merge and use how=‘left’